# Sync two folders via CD-based delta patch

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I have a folder of data on a remote PC that gets weekly updates, delivered by CD.

The folder is mostly `.jar` binary files - probably 200 of them, totalling around 350Mb in size.

Only a small portion of the data changes each time - typically about 5%.

Instead of providing a whole new version of the data-folder, I'd like to send deltas instead.

Is the Linux `diff` command the best way to do this?  The patch files it generates seem to be approaching 350Mb in size, so it's not bringing the size saving.

I'm not worried about sending over changes within specific files, I'm happy to send whole replacements.

Are there any other applicable Linux tools to do this?

Comment: How do you access the remote PC? If it's Windows would you be prepared to install one of the freely available [`rsyncd` tools](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)? If it's Linux/UNIX do you access it with `ssh` and if so does it have (could it have) `rsync` installed?

Comment: Hi @roaima - there isn't a connection between the two PCs, so CD is the only transfer mechanism.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you were sent a CD of updates that you needed to apply (presumably over some slow link) to the remote PC

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the sort of thing that `git bundle` would work well for.

It can create a file representing the changes to a repo over time that can be written to the CD to transfer to the remote machine. These changes can then be applied to the remote location.

> **EXAMPLES**
>
> Assume you want to transfer the history from a repository R1 on
>   machine A to another repository R2 on machine B. For whatever reason,
>   direct connection between A and B is not allowed, but we can move data
>   from A to B via some mechanism (CD, email, etc.). We want to update R2
>   with development made on the branch master in R1.

git bundle docs are [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `rsync --write-batch=FILE` for this requirement, but I think for only 350MB, being sent on a CD, it's probably overkill. (Whether you send 150MB or 350MB is largely irrelevant; it still takes one CD.)

If you were to use `rsync` in this way, you would need to maintain a local copy of the data folder against which the incoming changed files could be compared. The change-set output would be written to `FILE` and could then also be applied to the remote PC target with `rsync --read-batch=FILE`.

A better recommendation would be to use file modification date/time and size to allow `cp` to determine which files in the collection had been updated, and to simply copy those from the CD.

```
cp -u -r --preserve=timestamps /media/CD /path/to/target/folder
```

The `-u` flag here updates only files that are newer in the source, and the combination of `-r --preserve=timestamps` ensures that the entire directory tree is considered, with each copied file maintaining its timestamps.

Comment: Thanks for that @roaima . Sadly the timestamps do change for each new build. But, it would _probably_ be acceptable to use filename & filesize